# How to add values to an exisiting TPieSeries via Delphi Xe7

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe7

As the title suggest, how can I add a value to an already existing pie slice in a TPieseries within the TChart component.

delphi XE7 for iOS FMX

Comment: How did you set the value for that slice in the first place? Can't you just do that again with the new value?

Comment: You delete the existing slice and re-add it with the new values. See `TPieSeries.PieValues` in the documentation.

Comment: I know I can re-add the slice. But I was wondering if there was a built in function that allowed for incremental value adding. E.g., add green slice with value 5 -> iterate through loop -> find another green slice value with 3 -> append second green value -> green slice now = 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the indexed values through the `TPieSeries.PieValues` property.
Make an addition with the existing value. You can preinitialize the pie values with zero.

```
Series1.PieValues[2] := Series1.PieValues[2] + 10;
```

A better approach is to accumulate the values before adding them into the chart.

Comment: thanks. And yeah, that's what I ended up doing - getting values pre chart creation.